# Let $Ax=b$ be a linear system with matrix $A ∈ M_{4×4}$ and $\det(A)=3$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $Ax=b$ be a linear system with matrix  $A \in M_{4×4}$ and $\det (A) = 3$. If possible, give an example of matrices $A$ and $b$ such that
>   the following are true
>
> 1. The system has exactly one solution.
> 2. The system has no solutions
> 3. The system has infinite solutions.
>
> If any of these is not possible, explain why.

My first question about this question is, what is the best way to make up a matrix with a predefined determinant?  I guess if I make up every element but one then I can solve for that element to get the determinant that I want.  Is that the best way?

For the main part of the question, for (i), I think I could just come up with any $A$ that has the right $\det$ and then just any value for $b$

For (ii) and (iii), I think there is no way to write $A$ and $b$ to have either no solutions of infinite solutions since the determinant of $A$ is non-zero.

Comment: if $\det A \ne 0$ then it is "non-singular" which means that it has an inverse.  If it has an inverse then what happens when we multiply both side by $A^{-1}$

Comment: I would suggest you to take $A$ as a diagonal matrix.

Comment: @MathLover Is that a hint for finding a quick matrix or is it a hint towards the main part of the question?  Or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that for a diagonal matrix
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}a_1 & & \\&\ddots&\\&&a_n\end{pmatrix}
$$
holds $\det A = a_1\cdot\ldots\cdot a_n$.
If you like to have a specific determinant, you can also consider the case
$$
B=\begin{pmatrix}a & & & \\&1&&\\&&\ddots&\\&&&1\end{pmatrix}
$$
then you get $\det B=a$.

As you wrote: Since $\det A\neq 0$, the system has exactly one solution, given by $x=A^{-1}b$.